# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR for KML in chrome and firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, leaflet, kml, http2

Issue is only related to a single KML our site displays. We have multiple maps with KML's, this issue only affects one KML file which weighs in at 757 KB.   In an attempt to we fix are using preload on internet explorer. which resolved the issue on there, but not on chrome or firefox. (latest and earlier versions)   KML is loaded with leaflet.

All other KML's are 1/2 the size or smaller

PHP Version 7.3

This is not a new kml and nothing else has changed in the code, this site and map map has been up since 1st quarter 2018 without a problem.

What has me flummoxed is that the only thing that has changed was the upgrade from php 7.2 to 7.3. My next thought is to disable gzip compression.

Any guidance or theories appreciated.